# How to write w3c-conform Angular-Material applications?

Tags: angular-material, w3c-validation

I am writing a web application using AngularJS and Angular Material. I'd like to write valid HTML code (according to the w3c-validator).

I already know that I can write valid AngularJS directives like this:

```
<body data-ng-app="myApplication" data-ng-cloak>
```

However, AngularJS uses a lot of custom tags, such as:

```
<md-content></md-content>
```

I already tried several search queries on Duckduckgo, Google, and Stackoverflow but I can't find an answer on how to rewrite these tags in order to create valid HTML code.